# Issue in safari browse 5x with windows

Tags: javascript, safari, blob

I am getting this issue in safari browse 5x with windows:

```
'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating new Blob ([Myscript], { type: 'text/plain' })
```

Here is my code:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
if (window.webkitURL != null) {
 downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
 } else {
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
}
downloadLink.click();
$(downloadLink).parent().find(downloadLink).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari 5 is ***ancient***, and [does not support the File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) (you have to click the "Show All" button to even see it listed). Safari 5 on Windows was abandoned by Apple years ago, does not receive security updates, and has many known security vulnerabilities.

Bottom-line: Don't use Safari 5 on Windows, and if you do, don't expect it to support modern web technologies.

Comment: @vijaysai: ?! Dunno... Chrome? Firefox? IE9+? Opera?

Comment: @vijaysai: **Again:** Safari 5 on Windows is **obsolete** and **not supported by Apple**. Don't use it. Don't support it. Use a modern browser, and move on.